EsLint in Laravel 11 + vue3 and Vite
I am getting this error:
-> npm run lint
Oops! Something went wrong! :(



  ESLint: 9.7.0
    
    No files matching the pattern ".js,.vue" were found.
    Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

My code here: (I tried to remove this file as we already have .eslintrc.js, but the result is the same).
eslint.config.js
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import pluginVue from "eslint-plugin-vue";

export default [
  {files: ["**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,vue}"]},
  {files: ["**/*.js"], languageOptions: {sourceType: "script"}},
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/essential"],
];

/.vscode/settings.json
{
    "eslint.validate" : [
        "javascript",
        "javascriptvue",
        "vue"
    ],
    "eslint.format.enable" : true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit"
    },
    "vetur.validation.template": false

}

package.json
---------


 "scripts": {
            "dev": "vite",
            "build": "vite build",
            "lint": "eslint  .js,.vue resources/js ",
            "fix:eslint": "eslint --fix .js,.vue resources/js/  --debug",
    
        },



  "devDependencies": {
        "@eslint/js": "^9.7.0",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.5",
        "axios": "^1.6.4",
        "eslint": "^9.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.27.0",
        "globals": "^15.8.0",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0",
        "vite": "^5.0"
    },
---------

The errors are also no detected in Vscode and/or fixed automatically.
I tried many different configurations, but I cannot get this plugin to work with Laravel 11 + vue3 + vite.
Update: Sorry I forgot to add another file:
.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  
    root: true,
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',  'prettier'],
    parserOptions: {
      parser: 'babel-eslint',

      // ecmaVersion: 2020,
      // sourceType: 'module',
    },
    env: {
      amd: true,
      browser: true,
      node: true,
      es6: true,
    },
    rules: {
      indent: ['error', 2],
      quotes: ['warn', 'single'],
      semi: ['warn', 'never'],
      'no-unused-vars': ['error', { vars: 'all', args: 'after-used', ignoreRestSiblings: true }],
      'comma-dangle': ['warn', 'always-multiline'],
      'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
      'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
      'vue/no-v-html': 'off',
      'vue/require-default-prop': 'off',
      'vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline': 'off',
      'vue/html-self-closing': [
        'warn',
        {
          html: {
            void: 'always',
            normal: 'always',
            component: 'always',
          },
        },
      ],
      'vue/no-v-text-v-html-on-component': 'off',
    },
  }


Flat config by default in ESLint v9.0.0，is not the same as .eslintrc file.
If you want to use the.eslintrc configuration file, you will need to adjust the version of elsint below 8.57.0
